# no event OnClickListener in fragment button kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I am working kotlin. I have a fragment on my Activity . l want when click on button inside of fragment activity go to another activity .

this code my used in fragment class

```
class fragment_Arr :Fragment(), View.OnClickListener {
    override fun onClick(v: View?) {
        val intent = Intent(activity, FlightDeatilasDep::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)
    }


    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_arrivel,container,false)


        loadmorefilghtsbeforday.setOnClickListener{this}
    }



}
```

when l debug app and click on button no event happening !

Comment: loadmorefilghtsbeforday.setOnClickListener(this)

Comment: Is it compile? Because you writing code after return keyword in method.

Comment: And use correct brackets (this) for sure not {this}

Comment: it is same problem

Answer (score 0):

`loadmorefilghtsbeforday.setOnClickListener{}` body of the lambda is empty - nothing happen. 
Please register your listener by

```
 override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_arrivel,container,false)


    loadmorefilghtsbeforday.setOnClickListener(this)
    return view
}
```

or if you prefer using lambdas 
`loadmorefilghtsbeforday.setOnClickListener{ onClick(null) }` could be called but then your fragment don't need to implements View.OnClickListener.

and class names in Kotlin/java should start from capital later: FragmentArr. 
`_` is not recommended

Comment: same problem no event